# Sort Content from One DE based on Content in Another

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, ampscript

I am using the LookupOrderedRows function to pull information from a membership table and need to sort it based on data from a separate DE that contains all the group activity, I have tried a nested Row lookup which seems to be dropping information is there a better way to do this? I have included what I am currently doing below:

```
%%[ 
<!--set subscriber key-->
var @subkey
set @subkey= _subscriberkey
<!--End set subscriber key-->

var @membership_lookupValue, @membership_numRowsToReturn, @membership_rows, @membership_rowCount

    set @membership_lookupValue = "True"
    set @membership_numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
    set @membership_rows = LookupOrderedRows("ent.Membership",3,"favorite desc","approved",@membership_lookupValue,"user_id",@subkey)
    set @membership_rowCount = rowcount(@membership_rows)

]%%
<table class="responsive-table" style="padding: 0;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="padding: 15px 15px 0px 0px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #555556; font-size: 16px; line-height: 28px;" >
<span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:22px;">
%%[IF (@membership_rowCount == 1) THEN]%%
What is your Group up to?</span>

%%[ELSEIF (@membership_rowCount > 1) THEN]%%
What are your Groups up to?</span>

%%[ENDIF]%%
<br>Check out the chatter and leave some comments of your own.     
</td>
</tr>
<!--START FOR LOOP FOR MEMBERSHIP DE-->
%%[ if (@membership_rowCount > 0) then 

    var @membership_row, @membership_id, @active_group_lookupValue, @active_group_rows, @active_group_rowCount

    for @membership_i = 1 to @membership_rowcount do

    set @membership_row = row(@membership_rows,@membership_i) /*get row based on loop counter */
    set @membership_id = field(@membership_row, "group_id")

    set @active_group_lookupValue = "False"
    set @active_group_rows = LookupOrderedRows("ent.Group",0,"last_activity_at desc","deleted",@active_group_lookupValue,"id",@membership_id)
    set @active_group_rowCount = rowcount(@active_group_rows)
]%%
      <!--START FOR LOOP FOR GROUP DE-->
      %%[ if (@active_group_rowCount > 0) then 

        var @active_group_row, @group_name, @group_path, @membership_url

        set @active_group_row = row(@active_group_rows,1) /* get row #1 */
        set @group_name = field(@active_group_row, "name")
        set @group_path = field(@active_group_row, "path")
        set @membership_url = "/groups"

        for @active_group_i = 1 to @active_group_rowCount do
      ]%%

<tr>
<td align="left" style="padding: 5px 15px 0px 0px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #555556; font-size: 16px; line-height: 28px;" >
<strong>%%=v(@group_name)=%%</strong><br>
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@portal_url)=%%%%=v(@group_path)=%%" target="_blank" style="color: %%=v(@primary_color)=%%; text-decoration: none;" title="View Group Activity">View Group Activity</a>
</td>
</tr>
      %%[ next @active_group_i ]%%

      %%[else]%%
      <!--No Rows Found-->
      %%[endif]%%
      <!--END FOR LOOP FOR GROUP DE-->
%%[ next @membership_i ]%%

%%[else]%%
<!--No Rows Found-->
%%[endif]%%
<!--END FOR LOOP FOR MEMBERSHIP DE-->
<tr>
<td>
    <!-- Start CTA Button -->  
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px 15px 15px 0px;" align="left">
        <table class="responsive-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="70%" style="border:2px %%=v(@primary_color)=%% solid;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style="padding:12px 30px 12px 30px;" align="center"><a href="%%=RedirectTo(@portal_url)=%%%%=v(@membership_url)=%%" target="_blank" style="font-size: 22px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color: %%=v(@primary_color)=%%; text-decoration: none; text-transform:uppercase;" title="View All Groups">View All Groups</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- End CTA Button -->
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Queries would probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to combine `ent.Membership` and `ent.Group` together into one data extension.  That way you can order it with a single `LookupOrderedRows()` function.

Perhaps the target data extension -- `MembershipGroup` -- would have these columns:

```
user_id, approved, favorite, group_id, id, last_activity_at, name, path
```

The query would be something like this:

```
select 
m.user_id
, m.approved
, m.favorite
, m.group_id
, g.id
, g.last_activity_at
, g.name
, g.path
from ent.Membership m with (nolock) 
inner join ent.Group g with (nolock) on (g.id = m.group_id)
where m.approved = 'True' /* or 1 */
and g.deleted = 'False' /* or 0 */
```

In your lookupOrderedRows you could use something like:

```
LookupOrderedRows("ent.MembershipGroup",3,"favorite desc, last_activity_at desc","approved",@membership_lookupValue,"user_id",@subkey)
```

Comment: Great info, had to change the query just a little bit to base the id off of the membership data extension. Thanks for the great info everything filled in when I started the query.